# How to simplfy this loop

Tags: node.js

My doubt was i am able to insert array in loop succesfully but i need to simplyfy that code, so can any one suggest me to do that?

```
static async createProductReviewFromRequestBody(request_body) {
    let reviews_ratings = []
    for(let i in request_body.reviews_ratings)
    {
        let dict = {}
        dict['user_id'] = request_body.reviews_ratings[i].user_id,
        dict['user_full_name'] = request_body.reviews_ratings[i].user_full_name,
        dict['reviews_ratings_user_rating'] = request_body.reviews_ratings[i].reviews_ratings_user_rating,
        dict['reviews_ratings_description'] = request_body.reviews_ratings[i].reviews_ratings_description,
        dict['reviews_ratings_review_date'] = new Date(),
        dict['reviews_ratings_last_modified'] = new Date()
        reviews_ratings.push(dict)
    }
    return {
        product_id: request_body.product_id,
        reviews_ratings: reviews_ratings
    };
}
```

Comment: Is `request_body.reviews_ratings` an array?

Comment: @CertainPerformance `reviews_ratings`  its an array.

Comment: Most likely it could be done much cleaner with `map()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen can u please tell me how to do it?

Comment: How about consulting a reference, eg. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), on the topic ?

Answer (score 2):

Use `.map` to create a new array from every item in the old array. Save the `Date` at the beginning of the function, so you don't have to call `new Date()` every time, and iterate over an array of property names to keep things DRY:

```
static async createProductReviewFromRequestBody(request_body) {
  const now = new Date();
  const reviews_ratings = request_body.reviews_ratings
    .map((ratingsObj) => {
      const newObj = {
        reviews_ratings_review_date: now,
        reviews_ratings_last_modified: now
      };
      for (const prop of ['user_id', 'user_full_name', 'reviews_ratings_user_rating', 'reviews_ratings_description']) {
        newObj[prop] = ratingsObj[prop];
      }
      return newObj;
    });
  return {
    product_id: request_body.product_id,
    reviews_ratings // <-- can use property shorthand notation here
  };
}
```

Remember [not to use `for..in`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea) to iterate over arrays!